# Is this really the best way to update detached entities?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, webforms

I have the following code:

Get contact

```
public Contact LoadContactFromId(int contactId)
    {
        using(var ctx = new ContactContext())
        {
            var contact = ctx.Contacts.AsNoTracking().First(c => c.ContactId == contactId);

            return contact;
        }
    }
```

Update Contact

```
public void UpdateExistingContact(Contact updatedContact)
    {
        using(var ctx = new ContactContext())
        {
            ctx.Contacts.Attach(updatedContact);

            ctx.Entry(updatedContact).State = EntityState.Modified;

            foreach (var item in updatedContact.ContactPoints)
            {
                ctx.Entry(item).State = (item.ContactPointId == 0) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            }

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I am currently working with ASP.NET webforms and because of its stateless model, I can't keep working within the `DbContext`.  Because of this, I end up basically recreating the entire `Contact` entity from the POST data and then update it.

This seems like a horrible way to do this because I lose conncurrncey resolution since I'm not working with the true original entity and it seems kind of cumbersome to always have to recreate the object.

Is there an easier way to do this?  Am I looking at this all wrong?

Comment: Why not load the `Contact`, update its properties based on your POST data, and save it, all in one go?  In other words, why create a new `Contact` entity from scratch?

Comment: @JeremyTodd I have yet to find a good way to update the `Navigation Properties` of the entity.  Updating the `scalar properties` is a trival thing.  EG If I got the original entity and the updated entity, how could I easily, without having to code a whole method to just handle it, sync the `Navigation properties`?  I haven't seen one as of yet.  This is only compounded by the fact if I have a property where the only defining field is the entitiy key, I would have to pass it back and forth to know what property needs to be updated.

Comment: Why do you lose concurrency resolution?

Comment: @bmused Not lose exactly, but to track it I would have to send that to the client or re-query the database just to get it and then submit the new entity.  More work that I want.  Really looking for a "easy button" when I can easily sync the navigation properties to the original object.  Not seeing a way currently.